# diffpatch using the output of git diff directly

Tags: vimdiff, git

I guess many of you are like me, and even if they have been using ViM for years, still learn new features regularly. The last that I learned was

```
:diffp[atch] patch/name
```

Now, I want to combine it with git to compare the current version and a previous version. I can do, from ViM,

```
:!git diff <hash> filename > git.patch
:vert diffp git.patch
```

ViM will automatically recognise the direction of the patch, and I get to see the older file as a temporary file (`/tmp/file`).

Now, I have tried to get that in a single command, without having to write a patch file. In particular, I tried

```
:vert diffp < git diff <hash> filename
:vert diffp `< git diff <hash> filename`
:vert diffp `git diff <hash> filename`
```

but to no success. Is it at all possible, and if it is, how should one do it?

Comment: Similar post: [How can i view git diff for any commit using vim-fugitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369499/how-can-i-view-git-diff-for-any-commit-using-vim-fugitive/15370684#15370684)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I want to combine it with git to compare the current version and a previous version.
>
> ...
>
> Now, I have tried to get that in a single command, without having to write a patch file.

You can easily create a custom command to do this:

```
command! -nargs=? PreviousVersion diffthis |
      \ vnew |
      \ set buftype=nofile |
      \ set bufhidden=wipe |
      \ set noswapfile |
      \ execute "r!git show ".(!"<args>"?'head^':"<args>").":".expand('#') |
      \ 1d_ |
      \ let &filetype=getbufvar('#', '&filetype') |
      \ execute 'autocmd BufWipeout <buffer> diffoff!' |
      \ diffthis
```

You can now do `:PreviousVersion` to get the changes between the current buffer and the last commit (`head^`) or some arbitrary revision, e.g. `:PreviousVersion {revision}`

Note: you may want to use `<mods>` and `:new` if you want more control over the splitting.

#### Fugitive.vim

Alternatively, I would recommend using [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gdiff` command.

> I'm not going to lie to you; fugitive.vim may very well be the best Git wrapper of all time.

Use `:Gvdiff` to do the `:Gdiff` vertically.

Diff between the current file and the previous commit

```
:Gdiff head^
:Gvdiff head^
```

Diff between current file and the index

```
:Gdiff :0
```

Diff between current file and some other [revision]

```
:Gdiff [revision]
```

Diff between current file and current file 3 commits ago:

```
:Gdiff ~3
```

While `:Gdiff` is useful, I find `:Gblame` to be more useful. I can "re-blame" at on a certain line or open a commit to see the patch. This article explains how useful `git blame` can be: [Every line of code is always documented](https://mislav.net/2014/02/hidden-documentation/).

#### Vimcasts

[Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) has a [Fugitive series](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/) which I highly recommend. I would suggest looking at episodes: [Working with the git index](http://vimcasts.org/e/32) and [Resolving merge conflicts with vimdiff](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/).

#### For more help see

```
:h :diffthis
:h :vnew
:h :execute
:h :read
:h :delete
:h :_#
:h expand()
:h fugitive-:Gdiff
:h fugitive-revision
:h fugitive-:Gblame
```